# Elasticsearch: java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to window server

Tags: java, macos, elasticsearch, apache-tika

Trying to get Elasticsearch running and indexing PDFs. I'm not familiar with Java. What's the window server it's complaining about and how can I fix it?

```
Jun 13 15:57:23 server.mydomain.com java[22345] <Error>: kCGErrorFailure: Set a breakpoint @ CGErrorBreakpoint() to catch errors as they are logged.
Exception in thread "elasticsearch[index]-pool-2-thread-1" java.lang.InternalError: Can't connect to window server - not enough permissions.
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1827)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1724)
    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:823)
    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1045)
    at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:50)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1605)
    at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1627)
    at java.awt.Color.<clinit>(Color.java:263)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage.<clinit>(PDPage.java:80)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageNode.getAllKids(PDPageNode.java:212)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageNode.getAllKids(PDPageNode.java:218)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageNode.getAllKids(PDPageNode.java:184)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog.getAllPages(PDDocumentCatalog.java:211)
    at org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFTextStripper.writeText(PDFTextStripper.java:322)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDF2XHTML.process(PDF2XHTML.java:63)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.pdf.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:140)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:242)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parse(CompositeParser.java:242)
    at org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parse(AutoDetectParser.java:120)
    at org.elasticsearch.plugin.mapper.attachments.tika.TikaExtended.parseToString(TikaExtended.java:48)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.attachment.AttachmentMapper.parse(AttachmentMapper.java:309)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeValue(ObjectMapper.java:585)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:449)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:493)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:437)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareCreate(InternalIndexShard.java:290)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.index.TransportIndexAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportIndexAction.java:210)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:532)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:430)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to be able to properly index the PDF, ElasticSearch is asking Apache Tika to extract the text. Apache Tika in turn is asking Apache PDFBox to parse the file for processing. Because of the way that PDFs work, PDFBox needs to use Java AWT calls to do things like work out fonts, colours etc

Your machine is not currently correctly set up for Java to perform graphical operations, so when PDFBox tries to do something using AWT to process the PDF, it blows up.

You have two choices. One is to finish the graphical setup, the other is to tell Java to run in a headless mode.

If you google for your error message, then you'll find lots of helpful answers about how to perform the appropriate OSX setup for either option. [This one](http://ernstdehaan.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/mac-os-x-fonts-and-headless-java.html) looks to be a good example. In common with most of the unix varients of Java, if you run Java with

```
java -Djava.awt.headless=true
```

Then it'll use a headless mode, and won't hit permissions issues with the real graphics system.

Answer (score 2):

That is the result of your application trying to use AWT in a headless environment.

To fix it, launch your application with the option which tells AWT to use headless mode.

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```